# SQL: How to pick certain values based on boundary conditions?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to formulate a SQL to pick specific values from a column based on the boundary conditions. (DDLs Below).

Below is the expected output:

[image]

**Explanation:**
For the first row with Session_id (`A1XYZB0-A2825NDLA7WDZV-2021-03-15 16:46:06.899`) the action type would be None because it is neither `selectSearchHistory` or `selectISS` as in row number 2 and 3.

But for row 2, I have action_type `selectSearchHistory` and hence I pull in that value, rest remaining the same. For the 3rd row, I have selectISS and hence I pull that value, rest remaining the same

Here's what I have done so far:

```
select session_id, 
lag(action_type) over (partition by cust_id, device_event_date order by session_id) as prev_action_type,
tbl_name, marketplace_id, enc_customer_id, device_event_date, page_type, action_type,
ROW_NUMBER () over (partition by session_id order by session_id ) as rn
from test_table where action_type is NOT NULL;
```

I am not able to group them into a per action_type row as show in the image.

```
create table test_table (session_id varchar(200), table_name varchar(100), page_type varchar(100), action_type varchar(100), territory varchar(100), cust_id varchar(100), device_event_date timestamp);


INSERT INTO test_table VALUES('A1XYZB0-A2825NDLA7WDZV-2021-03-15 16:46:06.899','page_view','browseFind','','1','A1XYZB0','44270.6986909606');
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES('A1XYZB0-A2825NDLA7WDZV-2021-03-15 16:46:06.899','page_view','browseSearch','','1','A1XYZB0','44270.6987389699');
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES('A1XYZB0-A2825NDLA7WDZV-2021-03-15 16:46:06.899','clicks','browseSearch','initiateSearch','1','A1XYZB0','44270.6987484028');
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES('A1XYZB0-A2825NDLA7WDZV-2021-03-15 16:46:06.899','clicks','browseSearch','executeSearch','1','A1XYZB0','44270.6988179745');
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES('A1XYZB0-A2825NDLA7WDZV-2021-03-15 16:46:06.899','page_view','browseSearch','','1','A1XYZB0','44270.698827581');
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES('A1XYZB0-A2825NDLA7WDZV-2021-03-15 16:46:06.899','clicks','searchResults','playSong','1','A1XYZB0','44270.6989970139');
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES('A1XYZB0-A2825NDLA7WDZV-2021-03-15 16:46:06.899','plbk_attr_search','searchResults','','1','A1XYZB0','44270.6989970139');
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES('A1XYZB0-A2825NDLA7WDZV-2021-03-15 16:51:21.902','page_view','browseFind','','1','A1XYZB0','44270.7023368287');
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES('A1XYZB0-A2825NDLA7WDZV-2021-03-15 16:51:21.902','page_view','browseSearch','','1','A1XYZB0','44270.7023457292');
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES('A1XYZB0-A2825NDLA7WDZV-2021-03-15 16:51:21.902','clicks','browseSearch','selectSearchHistory','1','A1XYZB0','44270.7025611227');
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES('A1XYZB0-A2825NDLA7WDZV-2021-03-15 16:51:21.902','clicks','browseSearch','executeSearch','1','A1XYZB0','44270.7025611227');
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES('A1XYZB0-A2825NDLA7WDZV-2021-03-15 16:51:21.902','page_view','browseSearch','','1','A1XYZB0','44270.7025758102');
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES('A1XYZB0-A2825NDLA7WDZV-2021-03-15 16:51:21.902','clicks','searchResults','selectAlbum','1','A1XYZB0','44270.7026314236');
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES('A1XYZB0-A2825NDLA7WDZV-2021-03-15 16:51:21.902','plbk_attr_search','searchResults','','1','A1XYZB0','44270.7026314236');
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES('A1XYZB0-A2825NDLA7WDZV-2021-03-15 16:55:49.632','page_view','browseFind','','1','A1XYZB0','44270.7054355556');
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES('A1XYZB0-A2825NDLA7WDZV-2021-03-15 16:55:49.632','page_view','browseSearch','','1','A1XYZB0','44270.7054554398');
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES('A1XYZB0-A2825NDLA7WDZV-2021-03-15 16:55:49.632','clicks','browseSearch','initiateSearch','1','A1XYZB0','44270.7054703241');
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES('A1XYZB0-A2825NDLA7WDZV-2021-03-15 16:55:49.632','clicks','browseSearch','selectISS','1','A1XYZB0','44270.7055178704');
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES('A1XYZB0-A2825NDLA7WDZV-2021-03-15 16:55:49.632','clicks','browseSearch','executeSearch','1','A1XYZB0','44270.7055178704');
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES('A1XYZB0-A2825NDLA7WDZV-2021-03-15 16:55:49.632','page_view','browseSearch','','1','A1XYZB0','44270.7055278241');
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES('A1XYZB0-A2825NDLA7WDZV-2021-03-15 16:55:49.632','clicks','searchResults','playSong','1','A1XYZB0','44270.7055589236');
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES('A1XYZB0-A2825NDLA7WDZV-2021-03-15 16:55:49.632','plbk_attr_search','searchResults','','1','A1XYZB0','44270.7055589236');
```

The device_event_time stamp is epoch.

Comment: What rdbms are you using?

Comment: "not able" means what - error message, wrong result, nothing happens? What did you attempt? Did you try using posted query as source for an aggregate query?

Comment: Im using redshift

Comment: I tried using the "AND" "OR" combination

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure about your data or requirements, but here's a CTE approach that produces the output in your example...

```
WITH ssh AS
(
    SELECT session_id, action_type 
    FROM test_table 
    WHERE action_type = 'selectSearchHistory'
), siss AS
(
    SELECT session_id, action_type 
    FROM test_table 
    WHERE action_type = 'selectISS'
), s AS
(
    SELECT session_id, territory, cust_id 
    FROM test_table
    GROUP BY session_id, territory, cust_id  
)
SELECT 
    s.session_id,
    COALESCE(ssh.action_type, COALESCE(siss.action_type, 'None')) AS action_type,
    s.territory,
    s.cust_id
FROM s
LEFT JOIN ssh ON ssh.session_id = s.session_id
LEFT JOIN siss ON siss.session_id = s.session_id;
```

[Click here to see it in action & have a play in SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/c29752/7)